# How to get only ONE category of “Portfolio” posts to display on main page rather than ALL categories?

Tags: wp-query

I have a section on my main page that displays a new “Portfolio” post each time I write one no matter what category I assign them to. What I want to do is make the main page only display **one** specific category (`events`) from these Portfolio posts. I’m just wondering what I need to change in the below code to do that?

```
$args_for_latest = array(
    'numberposts'     => 5,
    'offset'          => 0,
    'orderby'         => 'port_date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'post_type'       => 'port',
    'tax_query'       => array(  
                            'taxonomy' => 'portcat',  
                            'field' => 'slug'
                        ),
    'post_status'     => 'publish' 
); 


$temp_latest = $wp_query;
$wp_query_latest= null;
$wp_query_latest = new WP_Query();
$wp_query_latest->query($args_for_latest);
while ($wp_query_latest->have_posts()) : $wp_query_latest->the_post();
$featured_image_latest = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );

$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'portcat');
$array_keys = array_keys($terms);

?>
    <li><center><?php if ($featured_image_latest[0]!=="") {
        echo "<img src='".TIMTHUMBURL."?w=120&h=120&src=".$featured_image_latest[0]."' alt='".get_the_title()."'>"; 
        } else { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo IMGURL; ?>/pic_article1.jpg" alt="" />
        <?php } ?>
        <span><?php  echo $terms[$array_keys[0]]->name;  ?></span>
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
        <?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0, 70)."..."; ?></center>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" class="read">Read more</a>                            
    </li>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried reading https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Oh thank you, that was perfect! Similarly, I'd like to display all portfolio categories but EXCLUDE 'events' in another section. I've tried the below and a few variations but it didn't work? $args_for_latest = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'offset' => 0, 'orderby' => 'port_date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'post_type' => 'port', 'post_status' => 'publish' 'tax_query' => array( 'taxonomy' => 'portcat', 'terms' => 'events' 'field' => 'slug', 'operator' => 'NOT IN' ) )
);

Comment: [Ask a new question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Please don’t misuse the answer field for questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wyck is correct. You can find the answer you seek in the wonderful Wordpress documentation.

But, 'cause why not, here's the answer for you:

You're very close, you just need to change your "tax_query" array to include the term you're requesting. Like this:

```
    'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                      'taxonomy' => 'portcat',
                      'field' => 'slug',
                      'terms' => 'events'
                    )
                  )
```

Comment: @Sam Please come back and accept an answer. I'm 99.9% sure this as the answer as you were simply missing a term in your tax query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.

```
$args_for_latest = array(
    'numberposts'     => 5,
    'category_name'   => 'events', ///Use category slug,not name.
    'offset'          => 0,
    'orderby'         => 'port_date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'post_type'       => 'port',
    'tax_query'       => array(  
                            'taxonomy' => 'portcat',  
                            'field' => 'slug'
                        ),
    'post_status'     => 'publish' 
);
```